# Textbook Accompanying Naive Set Theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory, reference-request, self-learning

I'm in the process of self-studying from the very popular Halmos book "Naive Set Theory" and I must say I can say only the best about the book. However, although the book has some excercises I would like if someone would suggest another resource that contains excercises about the substance of the before mentioned book. It doesn't really need to be a textbook, anything would work really. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Suppes [*Axiomatic Set Theory*](http://amzn.com/0486616304) sounds like it's at about the same level as Halmos' book.  It might be slightly more rigorous but is intended as an introductory book.  The notation is a little different from what I've seen in most other books but it is still well-written and has a lot of exercises.